# JUnit 5 Parameterized test @ArgumentsSource parameters not loading

Tags: testing, junit, junit5, parameterized-unit-test, parameterized-tests

I have created below **JUnit5** parameterized test with **ArgumentsSource** for loading arguments for the test:

```
public class DemoModelValidationTest {

public ParamsProvider paramsProvider;

public DemoModelValidationTest () {
    try {
         paramsProvider = new ParamsProvider();
    }
    catch (Exception iaex) {
        
    }
}
    
@ParameterizedTest
@ArgumentsSource(ParamsProvider.class)
void testAllConfigurations(int configIndex, String a) throws Exception {
  paramsProvider.executeSimulation(configIndex);
}
```

}

and the **ParamsProvider** class looks like below:

```
public class ParamsProvider implements ArgumentsProvider {
public static final String modelPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "demoModels";

YAMLDeserializer deserializedYAML;
MetaModelToValidationModel converter;
ValidationRunner runner;
List<Configuration> configurationList;
List<Arguments> listOfArguments;

public ParamsProvider() throws Exception {
    configurationList = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfArguments = new LinkedList<>();
    deserializedYAML = new YAMLDeserializer(modelPath);
    deserializedYAML.load();

    converter = new MetaModelToValidationModel(deserializedYAML);
    runner = converter.convert();
    configurationList = runner.getConfigurations();

    for (int i = 0; i < configurationList.size(); i++) {
        listOfArguments.add(Arguments.of(i, configurationList.get(i).getName()));
    }
}

public void executeSimulation(int configListIndex) throws Exception {
    final Configuration config = runner.getConfigurations().get(configListIndex);
    runner.run(config);
    runner.getReporter().consolePrintReport();
}

@Override
public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext context) {

    return listOfArguments.stream().map(Arguments::of);
    //      return Stream.of(Arguments.of(0, "Actuator Power"), Arguments.of(1, "Error Logging"));

}}
```

In the **provideArguments()** method, the commented out code is working fine, but the first line of code

```
listOfArguments.stream().map(Arguments::of)
```

is returning the following error:

> org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest

I am not sure whether I am having a casting problem for the stream in provideArguments() method, but I guess it somehow cannot map the elements of **listOfArguments** to the stream, which can finally take the form like below:

```
Stream.of(Arguments.of(0, "Actuator Power"), Arguments.of(1, "Error Logging"))
```

Am I missing a proper stream mapping of **listOfArguments**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`provideArguments(…)` is called *before* your test is invoked.

Your `ParamsProvider` class is instantiated by JUnit. Whatever you’re doing in `desiralizeAndCreateValidationRunnerInstance` should be done in the `ParamsProvider` constructor.

Also you’re already wrapping the values fro deserialised configurations to Arguments and you’re double wrapping them in `providesArguments`.

Do this:

```
@Override
public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext context) {

return listOfArguments.stream();

}}
```

Comment: Moved the code to constructor and getting following error:                                                 `Error converting parameter at index 0: No implicit conversion to convert object of type org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments$$Lambda$397/0x00000000639b9368 to type java.lang.Integer`

Comment: Post all of your code

Comment: Updated with full code

Comment: You’re double wrapping the arguments. I updated my answer.

Comment: I am already doing the same thing, what's the modification here?

Comment: Get rid of `.map`. Fixed the snippet. You’re double creating an Argument of an Argument